# Log image filename that's cached by external cdn using htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to keep a log of image file names whenever a specific cdn caches our images but I can't quite get it. Right now, my code looks something like:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Photon/1.0
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ log.php?image=$1 [L]
```

The above always logs the image as being "log.php" even if I'm making the cdn cache "example.jpg" and I thoroughly don't understand why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The above always logs the image as being "log.php" even if I'm making the cdn cache "example.jpg" and I thoroughly don't understand why.

Because in `.htaccess` the rewrite engine loops until the URL passes through unchanged (despite the presence of the `L` flag) and your rule also matches `log.php` (your rule matches *everything*) - so this is the "image" that is ultimately logged. The `L` flag simply stops the current *pass* through the rewrite engine.

For example:

1. Request `/example.jpg`
2. Request is rewritten to `log.php?image=example.jpg`
3. Rewrite engine starts over, passing `/log.php?image=example.jpg` to the start of the second pass.
4. Request is rewritten to `log.php?image=log.php` by the same `RewriteRule` directive.
5. Rewrite engine starts over, passing `/log.php?image=log.php` to the start of the third pass.
6. Request is rewritten to `log.php?image=log.php` (again).
7. URL has not changed in the last pass - processing stops.

You need to make an exception so that `log.php` itself is not processed. Or, state that all non-`.php` files are processed (instead of *everything*). Or, if only images are meant to be processed then only check for images.

For example:

```
# Log images only
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Photon/1\.0
RewriteRule ^(.+\.(?:png|jpg|webp|gif))$ log.php?image=$1 [L]
```

Remember to backslash-escape literal dots in the regex.

Or,

```
# Log Everything except log.php itself
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Photon/1\.0
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(.+)
RewriteRule !^log\.php$ log.php?image=%1 [L]
```

In the last example, `%1` refers to the captured subpattern in the preceding *CondPattern*. I only did it this way, rather than using `REQUEST_URI` directly since you are excluding the slash prefix in your original logging directive (ie. you are passing `image.jpg` to your script when `/image.jpg` is requested). If you want to log the slash prefix as well, then you can omit the 2nd *condition* and pass `REQUEST_URI` directly. For example:

```
# Log Everything except log.php itself (include slash prefix)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Photon/1.0
RewriteRule !^log\.php$ log.php?image=%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

Alternatively, on Apache 2.4+ you can use the `END` flag instead of `L` to force the rewrite engine to stop and prevent further passes through the rewrite engine. For example:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Photon/1\.0
RewriteRule (.+) log.php?image=$1 [END]
```

Comment: Awesome! This makes a lot of sense. Guess I never ran into a similar problem before since my htaccess file luckily hasn't looped problematically prior to this issue. I changed it to "RewriteRule !^log.php$ log.php?image=%{REQUEST_URI}" and it works perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: @user1413341 You're welcome. This "looping" is a common cause of "500 Internal Server Errors" - when it gets stuck in an infinite loop. (By default, the server stops after 10 internal loops, but breaks with an error.)